# new to scala anyone explain the code for me?

Tags: scala

```
 def indexOf[T](seq: Seq[T],value: T, from: Int):Int={
    for(i<-from until seq.length){
     if(seq(i)== value) return i
       }
       -1
         }
```

Anyone explain to me `indexOf[T]` meaning? And what does `(seq:Seq[T],value:T)` do?

Comment: I am pretty sure it would have been easier checking any syntax tutorial like the Tour of Scala, rather than opening an SO question.

Answer (score 4):

- `def indexOf` - This is a method. We'll call it `indexOf`.
- `[T]` - This method will make reference to an unspecified type. We'll call it `T`.
- `(seq:Seq[T], value:T, from:Int)` - This method will take 3 passed parameters:

  1. variable `seq` which is a `Seq` of elements of type `T`
  2. variable `value` which is a single value of type `T`
  3. variable `from` which is a single value of type `Int`
- `:Int` - This method returns a value of type `Int`.
- `= {` - Mehod code begins here.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to Scala generics.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/generic-classes.html

In simple terms, here, `T` acts as a place holder for any data type.

The indexOf function takes a generic `T`, which during runtime can be a Integer, String or custom Employee object.

For example in the sequence, you can pass a Seq of Employee or String and same data type value.

By using generics, for your example, you dont have to create different indexOf function for every other data type.

How to call indexOf? As below:

```
val index = indexOf[String](stringSeq, "searchThis", 0)
```

or

```
val index = indexOf[Employee](employeeSeq, empObj, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is what we call a parametric method in scala.

> Parametric methods in Scala can be parameterized by type as well as
> value. The syntax is similar to that of generic classes. Type
> parameters are enclosed in square brackets, while value parameters are
> enclosed in parentheses.

Since T is a generic type, that means that *indexOf* method can be called on a variety of types.

Your method *indexOf[T]* takes a type parameter *T* and value parameters *seq*, *value* and *from*.
When calling your method, you can either set explicitly the type you will be manipulating by replacing the T by your concrete type (see example 1), or let the compiler work for you (type inference) based on the parameter type of your param *seq* and *value*. (see example 2)

Example 1

```
 val index = indexOf[Int](Seq(3, 5, 4), 4, 0)
```

Example 2

```
 val index = indexOf(Seq("alice", "bob", "yo"), "bob", 1)
```